# Can't mount a device using label

Tags: mount, disk-image

I am trying to create a 60 MB virtual hard disk, then format that hard disk to have an EXT4 file system, and a label name of it *database*.
I am running the following

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=VHD.img bs=1M count=60
```

to create the disk and then

```
mkfs.ext4 VHD.img -L database
```

to format and label it. Everything works fine until here, but when I am trying to mount it using the label/name by running the

```
mount -L database /engr
```

it says

```
(mount: /engr: can't find LABEL= "database")
```

Any Idea why?

Answer (score 1):

The mount label option works only for block devices because it uses libblkid to search for the label and it only searches block devices. Which makes sense, imagine mount scanning every single file to check if it is a disk image formatted to ext4 with specific label, that would take forever :)

You either need to mount it using the file name `mount VHD.img /engr` or create a loop device `sudo losetup -f VHD.img` and mount then you can mount the `/dev/loop0` device using label.